# Span ignores style info and .html() updates

Tags: html

In this form I have a user message `<span>`. It ignores the style info given in the HTML and in the CSS style sheet.  Also, if I update the  using .html() the new text isn't show.

```
$('#matting').append('<div id="register_user_box" class="inline_form" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px; <br/><span id="user_msg" style="width: 90%; height: 15px; color: red; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px;">Info msg</span><br/><form id="register_user_id" name="register_user_form"> <button id="cancel" onclick="cancel_register(); return false;" style="width: 63px; float: right; margin-right:8px;">Cancel</button> <button id="register" onclick="register_user(); return false;" style="width: 63px; float: right;">Save</button> </form></div>');
```

The info specified in style for user_msg is ignored.  If I update the text with `$('#user_msg').html(message);` this is also ignored.  What could explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Syntax error - you didn't close your `<div>` or the style attribute inside of it:

```
$('#matting').append('<div id="register_user_box" class="inline_form"'+
  ' style="position: absolute; top: 20px; right: 10px; ' + // missing ">! 
  '<br/><span id="user_msg" style="width: 90%; height: 15px;'+
  'color: red; font-family: Arial; font-size: 11px;">Info msg</span> '+
  '<br/><form id="register_user_id" name="register_user_form">'+
  '<button id="cancel" onclick="cancel_register(); return false;"'+
  ' style="width: 63px; float: right; margin-right:8px;">Cancel</button>'+
  ' <button id="register" onclick="register_user(); return false;"'+
  'style="width: 63px; float: right;">Save</button> </form></div>');
```

Also notice that `<span>`'s are inline elements (see [scrappedcola's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10216850/1139697)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for finding the problem.  My mind must have been thinking about something else.

Answer (score 1):

`<span>`'s are inline elements. To give it height and width use the css `display:inline-block;` To add the text message try using `$('#user_msg').text(message);`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information.  The problem was what zeta found.